# Copy range from sheet1 to sheet2 based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code. It works well I have only one problem with it. It copies all rows from Sheet1 (columns A-D). The last column (D) includes the criteria string and I would not like to copy/paste that column.
Thank you

```
 Sub CopyInfo()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Sheet1.Range("A3:C1000", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 4, "Applicable"
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).Copy Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheet2.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only copy the first 3 columns:

```
.Offset(1).Resize(,3).Copy Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Comment: Another issue with this code. When the it is executed all rows on sheet1 are copied to sheet2. I wonder if there is a way to copy only newly added rows to sheet1, i.e. I have 8 rows that meet the criteria, I run the code and all 8 are copied to sheet2. Next, I add two new rows to sheet 1 that meet the criteria. When I run the code, only two new rows are copied to sheet2.

Comment: That probably needs a new question - you would need some way to check each row against each row on sheet2 to determine if it had already been copied there.

Comment: Tim, I have a follow up question to this code.the current code copies rows from Sheet1 to Sheet2 based on the criteria "Applicable". I wonder if the code can be updated to do the following:

1. Add another criterion of  "Not Applicable" to the "Applicable" in the current code
Sheet2
2. The rows copied by criterion "Not Applicable" to be the hidden rows on Sheet2.

Comment: Do you mean the rows with "Not Applicable" as actual content, or the rows which do not contain "Applicable" ?

Comment: ...either way, better to post a new question for this.

Comment: I posted it under "How to copy range from sheet1 to sheet2 based on criteria". I appreciate your feedback